# Cabling problems to consider at 30m

Tags: electrical, uk, workshop

I have just had a workshop built on the side of the house and will be setting the electrics up.

The question I have is based on the distance I have going from my mains inlet (via a Henley block) and the underground (trench) route to the new CU (100amp mains switch) in the workshop.

I was planning to use 25mm SWA 3 core or 2 core cable for the 30m run around the house and was wondering if there are any concerns about resistance in the cable effecting the tripping abilities on the MCDs. the CU will have RCD protection but I am not up with any of the calculations needed to work this out.

Some other info. I be using a few 32amp radial circuits with 4mm T&E and a 6amp lighting circuit. one of the radial circuits will support a TIG.

Also, what earthing option would you suggest/do I have?

Any thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So you're where on the planet? Rules and practices vary by locale. Sounds rather UK or former commonwealth

Comment: Well spotted. I am in the UK, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Your local electrical code will list the minimum wire size allowed.  For heavy use(32amps) at 30 meters, I would probably bump up minimum wire size by one size.

Answer (score 0):

First, work out your maximum load current.  There are different ways to do diversity calculations, but one is to use 100% of your largest circuit (32A presumably) and 40% of the other circuits.  For example, suppose you have two more 32A radials and a 6A lighting circuit, that would be:

Diversity current = 32 + 0.4*(32+32+6) = 60A

If your TIG is going to take more than 32A you might revise this calculation.

Feed that into [a cable size calculator](https://www.elandcables.com/cable-calculator) and picking 'enclosed in conduit in trunking' it indicates 16mm2 of 70degC twin and earth cable, or 10mm2 of 90degC T&E.  Of course you are free to install thicker cable than this, although it will be more expensive.

We can calculate the line to earth trip current by considering the line conductor resistance (R1) and the earth conductor resistance (R2).  [Tables of R1+R2 exist](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470998373.app4), which gives R1+R2 for 16mm2 T&E to be max 2.3 ohms/km.  So:

R_cable for 16mm2 = 2.3 * (30/1000) = 0.069 ohms

Fault current = 230 / 0.069 = 3333 amps

I wouldn't worry about the cable resistance not tripping the MCB!

On earthing, it first depends on what earthing system your house is on - TNS, TNCS (also called PME), or TT - and whether the outbuilding has any exposed metalwork, eg a steel structure or pipes.  There are [guides](https://professional-electrician.com/technical/tnc-s-supplies-for-outbuildings-thinking-outside-the-box-napit/) and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvENsVUhDUs) which may be worth studying to understand your options.